# phpstorm on osx: shortcut for 'Comment with Line Comment'

Tags: macos, shortcut, phpstorm

seems like i still didn't fully transform into a mac user (coming from Windows), once again having trouble with the keyboard shortcuts:

in phpstorm the following shortcut for 'Comment with Line Comment' is shown in the dropdown menu:

[image: comment shortcut]

now, problem being, there is no '/' key on my keyboard, typing a slash means pressing 'SHIFT+7' for me.

i already found the keymap options on phpstorm (currently using 'Mac OS X 10.5+) and tried changing the shortcut there but didn't get anywhere so far.

**UPDATE 27. Sep. 2018**

- Just found this blog post, help with the mapping on german mac laptop keyboards: 
  https://victorvolle.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/intellij-german-keyboard-shortcuts-reference/
- Also found out that I have a '/' character on the numeric pad part of my german keyboard, an it seems to act like the '/' key on english keyboards, so can use for the 'Comment with line Comment' shortcut `⌘/`

Comment: Create your own keymap by duplicating/copying bundled `Mac OS X 10.5+` and then assign any shortcut you want to any command. If still not able to *"get anywhere far"* then please describe what kind of problems you are facing.

Comment: thanks for comment, i got it working now. before, i got stuck on the 'add keyboard shortcut' window because i thought i'm expected to press *only one* button when the 'First Stroke' textfield has focus. would you like to add your comment as an answer, so i can mark it as accepted?

Comment: I do not think I have provided anything that worth calling "an answer". You can post your own solution/explanation as an answer.

Comment: In 2019 I am still having a bigger problem, also on a German Mac keyboard layout. I do not have a numpad on my keyboard. So in order to get _ I have to use shift+"-". And it does not work. Do you have any idea might help?

Comment: @akcasoy works for me, i suggest you post a new question on the issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the comment shortcut without editing the keymap.
Just press on "=" button, on the right of the ":" button when doing your shorcut.

You can validate this behavior in the keymap editor: pressing the ":" button will show you the "." caracter instead.

But there's still a wrong keyboard mapping.

Comment: not exactly sure about your description, but you got me on the right track: i can confirm that pressing the '-' key results in an '/', actually solving my problem. thanks for this

Answer (score 6):

[image]

damn muricans! wait, JetBrains is located in CZ, damn czechs! ;)

Comment: don't call it issue, call it feature hehe

p.s. i've had to deal with US keyboards in highschool working on old solaris machines

Comment: unfortunately something seems to have changed with a recent phpstorm update (i'm currently on 2017.2), as the minus (-) sign now seems to be where it belongs (pressing 'apple' key + '-' now does 'collapse code') - but where's the slash (/) now?...

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in my comment above, i managed to create my own shortcut by editing the keymap options. the thing i didn't understand in the 'add keyboard shortcut' dialog was that i thought i'm expected to press *only one* button when the 'First Stroke' textfield has focus.

i'd still be interested though why the default shortcut is something i can't even type on my keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I use two tricks to work around what I guess is a bug.

- `Ctl + Maj + A`, then typing "comment" is enough to choose "Comment with Line comment" with the "Return" key.
- Using the caps lock, that will let the `Cmd + /` work as expected